# How to call a custom service?

Tags: rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My service (AddTask.srv) is defined as:

```
string       name          
string       type         
string[]     behaviour     
uint16       priority     
bool         visibility   
string[]     parameters
```

and my rosservice call is

```
rosservice call /mynamespace/addTask \
'name: "mytask", type: "TaskPoP", behaviour: ["TaskBehFO", "10"], priority: 1, visibility: 1, parameters: ["gripper_r_base", "0", "0", "0.1", "gripper_l_base", "1", "0", "0", "0.2"]'
```

and I get this error message:

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "<string>", line 1, column 1:
    name: "mytask", type: "TaskPoP", ... 
    ^
expected <block end>, but found ','
  in "<string>", line 1, column 15:
    name: "mytask", type: "TaskPoP", behaviour: [" ...
```

What does the error message mean and how do I resolve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240573/how-to-call-a-custom-service?/) by [neckutrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/27626/neckutrek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The commas must be exchanged for line-breaks as such:

```
rosservice call /mynamespace/addTask \
'name: "mytask"
type: "TaskPoP"
behaviour: ["TaskBehFO", "10"]
priority: 1
visibility: 1
parameters: ["gripper_r_base", "0", "0", "0.1", "gripper_l_base", "1", "0", "0", "0.2"]'
```

---

Originally posted by [neckutrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/27626/neckutrek/) with karma: 26 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0